# Referencing Python method documentation without full class name in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, cross-reference

I'm trying to reference

```
http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__
```

from my python Sphinx documentation, and would like the link in the documentation to look as it would for a func `:func:` role if `__enter__` were implemented in the current class (i.e, in the same style and simply as **`__enter__`** and not as **`object.__enter__`**.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have set up [intersphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/intersphinx.html), the following markup will produce a hyperlink to the specified target in the Python documentation with the link text **`__enter__`**:

```
:meth:`__enter__ <object.__enter__>`
```

An alternative:

```
:meth:`~.object.__enter__`
```

This will result in the link text `__enter__()` (with parentheses by default; see http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-add_function_parentheses).

Or just use this:

```
`__enter__ <http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__enter__>`_
```

See http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#cross-referencing-syntax and http://sphinx-doc.org/rest.html#hyperlinks.